# Use dynamic table name in sql server query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I have an `Error` table which stores the names of the **table** in which the error occurred.
Now I want to query the table using the table name selected from the "Error" table.

I tried to store the table name in a variable and use this variable in the FROM clause in my query. But this doesn't work:

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(15)

select @tableName = TableName from SyncErrorRecords where Status = 'Unsynced'

select * from @tableName
```

Can anyone help me out on this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Share the `Query` that  you tried. @Ravi

Comment: Tables aren't *parameters*. The executalbe code generated by the query, ie the execution plan depends on the table schema, indexes and statistics. You don't even need "dynamic tables" anyway, there are far cleaner and easier ways to do whatever it is you want to do. What *is* it that you want to do? Why don't you use a UNION or a view?

Comment: "dynamic tables" are typically a smell that suggests you want to do something else. Eg implement inheritance, combine multiple tables with similar fields (similar to inheritance) or recombine partitioned tables. There are proper ways to solve the actual problem, eg by using view with UNION or UNION ALL, *partitioned views* that will automatically select the correct table based on the query criteria, creating a single partitioned table and more. They are a lot cleaner, faster and *easier* to maintain. Imagine *not* having to specify the tablename in the query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `Dynamic SQL`

either

```
declare @sql nvarchar(max)
select @sql = 'select * from ' + quotename(@tableName)

exec (@sql)
```

or

```
exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Answer (score 0):

The Query as follows.

```
DECLARE @tableName VARCHAR(15),
        @Qry VARCHAR(4000)
SELECT @tableName = TableName FROM SyncErrorRecords WHERE Status = 'Unsynced'
SET @Qry = 'SELECT * FROM ' +  @tableName
EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Qry
```